# Why is is my backstack entrycount always zero?

Tags: android

I'm adding my fragments like this:

```
  FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, fragment, "SettingsActivity")
            .addToBackStack("SettingsActivity")
            .commit();
```

Now when I push the backbutton the program comes in my overridden onBackPress:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d(TAG, "OnBackPressed");
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got entry.");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG,"NO entry");
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

I always get the result 0. I'm never getting in the Got Entry part.

Am I adding the fragments wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

This will finish the current activity.

Comment: Omg, that I didn't saw that one. Thanks.